# Error while building android apk in ionic 3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, ionic-view

```
(node:7592) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejec
tion id: 1): [object Object]

(node:7592) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I am facing these error when I run

```
ionic cordova build android
```

Comment: do you mean _build_ ? Also try with `--verbose` flag

Comment: please try not to directly make a build.. first check `ionic serve` is working or not ..

Comment: ionic serve is working and its shows output in webview

Comment: did you tried ionic cordova run android?

Comment: yes i tried but that also shows same error